# ¿cómo puedo hacer que los dos contenedores debajo del nav, queden de tal manera alineados verticalmente?

Tags: html, css, html5

estoy realizando prácticas con flex, pero no encuentro la manera que los divs me queden verticalmente alineados como la imagen, agradezco ayuda <3.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sin código (a ciegas) es muy difícil ayudarte. Adjunta un [repro]. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

Deberias poner tu codigo pero estoy de animo:

```css
.container-columna{
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
 }
 .container-fila{
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
 }
 .container-columna div, .container-fila div{
  background-color: aqua;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
 }
```

```html
<p>Alineacion en columnas</p>
 <div class="container-columna">
  <div>
   Div1
  </div>
  <div>
   Div2
  </div>
  <div>
   Div3
  </div>
 </div>
 <p>Alineacion en filas</p>
 <div class="container-fila">
  <div>
   Div1
  </div>
  <div>
   Div2
  </div>
  <div>
   Div3
  </div>
 </div>
```